# Valgrind: Conditional jump, uninitialised value, C++ basic code

Tags: c++, valgrind

This is my 1st question here, I am currently learning C++ and  I am working on how to use Valgrind. This program started with 71 errors and I have been able to minimize it down to 2, I just can't figure out the remaining problems, due to my inexperience with C++. Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong here or at least point me in a good direction? I understand what the error is telling me, I'm just not seeing the issue. Thanks for any help.

Here is the program code:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <cstdlib>
  using namespace std;

  int* initArray(int);
  int fillArray(int *, int);
  int* doubleArray(int *, int);
  void displayArray(int *, int);

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    if (argc != 2){
        cout << "wrong number of arguments" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    srand(time(0));

    int* ptr = new int[*initArray(n)];    //***Here is line 38***
    fillArray(ptr, n);
    displayArray(ptr, n);

    int* dptr = doubleArray(ptr, n);
    fillArray(ptr, 2*n);
    displayArray(ptr, 2*n);
}

int* initArray(int n){
    int arr[n];
    int *ptr = arr;
    return ptr;
}

int fillArray(int *ptr, int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        ptr[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
}

int* doubleArray(int * ptr, int n){
    int size = 2 * n;
    int * tmp = new int[size];
    ptr = tmp;
    delete [] tmp;
    return ptr;
    delete [] ptr;
}

void displayArray(int *ptr, int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout << ptr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

And here is my error output from valgrind:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsPtr.png
(it says I need 10 repuation to post it as an image, sorry!)

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `initArray` returns the address of the about-to-be-deceased `int arr[n]`.  Your code invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Why using so many pointers at all in your code? These aren't necessary, and make your code fragile and error prone.

Comment: _"it says I need 10 repuation to post it as an image, sorry!"_ For good reasons, you're obliged to post information as text as much as possible.

Comment: Wanted to add, `doubleArray` has *multiple* logic isues. Don't code your algorithm while you design it. Design it, *then* code it. Fwiw, `fillArray` looks correct, so you have that going for you, as does `displayArray` (though there the pointer param should ideally be `const`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As WhozCraig correctly pointed, one of your problems lies in function `initArray`. I'm not sure what you wanted to achieve in it, but for me it looks like you can simply omit it and use `int* ptr = new int[n];` at line 38.

Essentially you returned pointer to uninitiated memory on a stack, and then tried to allocate array with size of size equal to whatever it points. Valgrid message told you that.

But after you trigered UB (in `initArray`) your program legally can do *anything*.

But there are more errors in your code:

1. You did not `delete`d array pointed by `ptr` before exiting `main`.
2. You can not copy array's content by assigning pointers (`ptr = tmp`). To do this you need to iterate over array and copy elements one by one.
3. Your statement `delete [] ptr;` will never be executed.

And one general note: If learning pointers isn't your goal, avoid them — in your case right solution is to use `std::vector`.